# Expectation Values

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that $\{X_n\}_{n\ge1}$ take values $-\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $\dfrac{1}{2}$ with probability $a$ and $1-a$ respectively and $0$ otherwise. Suppose further that they are independent and discrete and random.

Then, how do I calculate the limit of $E\left[\dfrac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{3^n}\right]$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

If I had just variables and probability, I would use $$E[X]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ip_i$$. But I am not sure about distribution of these values or whatsoever.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E\left[\sum{\dfrac{x}{a}}\right] = \dfrac{\sum{E[x]}}{a}$, you have that

$$
E\left[\frac{X_1+X_2 + ...+X_n}{n^3}\right] = \dfrac{n*E[X]}{n^3} = \dfrac{n*(-1/2*\alpha + 1/2*(1-\alpha))}{n^3}=\dfrac{n*(1/2-\alpha)}{n^3}=\dfrac{1/2-\alpha}{n^2}
$$

The rest is simple.

Comment: $E[\frac{X_1+X_2 + ...+X_n}{n^3}] = n*E[X]$? Is this assumption always the case?

Comment: If the variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are IID (Independent and identically distributed), so $E[\sum{X_n}] = n*E[X]$ always. Another property is that, for $a$ being a constant, $E[aX] = aE[X]$. Using both properties you can get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say

$\displaystyle\left|\sum_{k=0}^n X_i\right|<n/2$, hence $\dfrac{E[\sum_{k=0}^n X_i]}{3^n}\to 0$ quite fast.